# truffle and metacoin. How can I send a transaction?

Tags: truffle

I am trying to learn truffle, and I have compiled, migrated, and test the example contract.  I load the example Dapp in my browser from local host, and I have the lists of addresses created by testRPC, but I cannot send any tokens because I have no balance.  This is even though the Dapp put 1000 Metacoin in the first account.

The log, obviously says that I don't have enough funds.  I am just trying to get a hang of these very simple things so I can move on to more complicated examples and start to build things myself but I am getting stuck.

Comment: Did you hardcode any address? Did you start TestRPC with `--accounts="2"`?

Comment: that just creates 2 accounts instead of 10 so doesn't really solve the problem

Comment: `--accounts="10"` should create 10 accounts.

Comment: yes, but the number of accounts isn't the issue.  It's finding a way to import the accounts into a wallet

Answer (score 1):

**testrpc** assigns a random balance to each account on startup. All accounts are created randomly every time a new instance is launched. Make sure you update addresses in the contracts with the new addresses **testrpc** generates each time you launch it.

Use **truffle** to [test](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/testing/) the contracts before deplying them on the main/private net (using a full client such as **geth**).

Comment: I realize that I need to load the mnemonic code into a client.  I was using metamask but there is no option to import a wallet.

Answer (score -1):

Install & use [truffle-hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider) inside `truffle.js`

> HD Wallet-enabled Web3 provider. Use it to sign transactions for addresses derived from a 12-word mnemonic.